# ModelState overwrites MultiSelectList values after post

Tags: forms, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, multi-select, modelstate

have a strange problem.

During POST action of a form which contains a MultiSelectList I can see all the selected values... so far so good.
But if there is a need to reshow the form because of some validation errors with other fields the MultiSelectList Dropdown field shows only the first selected value and not all values that were selected during the first request...

When i call ModelState.Clear() before returning the view I am able to rebuild the multi selected values list from database and also all selected values are shown... but this behaviour is not 100 % what i want.

I just want to reuse the selected Ids i get from the post request but somehow these values are overwriten by the modelstate in a way that only the first selected value is shown.

here some code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Employer(EmployerViewModel model)
{
...
model.IndustrialSectorsMultiSelectList = new MultiSelectList(industrialSectors, "Id", "Name", model.IndustrialSectorsSelectedIds);
...
return View(model);
}
```

When i debug my code i can see that model.IndustrialSectorsSelectedIds contain all the selected values... but in the View suddenly only the first value is shown.

Someone here to help? :-)

Thanks in advance!!!
Simon

**UPDATE**

Sorry if I was not clear enough. I don't use ModelState.Clear(). This is just one of the things i tried to find out whats going on and why even my manually set values are not taken during Post while they work as it should during Get. It helped me to find out that it's really the ModelState which overwrites my posted values in a way that only the first selected value is shown.

It seems that the selected values are passed as comma separated string "12,18,33,47". And when I recreate the View during HttpPost Action it only takes "12" and ignores the rest of the list.

Here more code:

ViewModel:

```
public MultiSelectList IndustrialSectorsMultiSelectList { get; set; }
public int[] IndustrialSectorsSelectedIds { get; set; }
```

Get action:

```
EmployerViewModel model = new EmployerViewModel();
Employer employer = ServiceManager.EmployerService.GetEmployerByUser(AppUser);
...
var industrialSectors = ServiceManager.DefaultValuesService.GetIndustrialSectors();
model.IndustrialSectorsMultiSelectList = new MultiSelectList(industrialSectors, "Id", "Name", employer.IndustrialSectors.Select(item => item.Id).ToList());
```

Post action when i need to reshow the view:

```
var industrialSectors = ServiceManager.DefaultValuesService.GetIndustrialSectors();
model.IndustrialSectorsMultiSelectList = new MultiSelectList(industrialSectors, "Id", "Name", model.IndustrialSectorsSelectedIds);
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IndustrialSectorsSelectedIds, Model.IndustrialSectorsMultiSelectList, new { @class = "select_branche form-control", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

As said... During GET the selected values are correctly shown in the View.
During Post only the first selected value from model is taken even when all selected values are in my int[] during post action. So the int[] I pass to the new MultiSelectList is fine.
Just for testing i tried to build the View during Post with exact the same code I have in Get action... During Get i see all values... during post only the first.

Don't know what to do :-(

**UPDATE 2**

I managed to get this behaviour fixed when i add the following lines to my post action method. Removing the int[] from ModelState and set the int[] = null within my ViewModel.

```
var industrialSectors = ServiceManager.DefaultValuesService.GetIndustrialSectors();
model.IndustrialSectorsMultiSelectList = new MultiSelectList(industrialSectors, "Id", "Name", model.IndustrialSectorsSelectedIds);
//Fix issue that modelstate value only sets the first selected value
ModelState.Remove("IndustrialSectorsSelectedIds");
model.IndustrialSectorsSelectedIds = null;
```

But still i don't know why it behaves like that. Is this some kind of bug?!
Any comments would be great. Thanks!!

Comment: There is no point in adding the last parameter in the `MultiSelectList` constructor if you binding to a property (its ignored). Show your view for this property. And why are you calling `ModelState.Clear()`? And where do you do that?

Comment: Can you please show the code in the razor view to display the `MultiSelectList`  ?

Comment: Thanks for reading :-) I updated my post hope that helps...

Comment: Added another update to my post... would be really great if someone can comment if this is a bug or if this works by design like that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry maybe I am just too stupid...

When changing the DropDownListFor to ListBoxFor in my View everything works as it should. :-)